# Is it possible to remap headphone inline controls?

Tags: headphones, input-source

Currently, when I press the volume up and down buttons on my Apple headphones connected to my Mac, it turns the volume up or down. Let's say I want to perform some other type of action when I press these inline control buttons. Is there any way to remap these buttons to do what I want, such as pressing a keyboard shortcut or causing a click somewhere?

Comment: Nope, but you can use the USB plug for PS4 or Xbox controllers... https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/use-ps4-xbox-controller-mac-3626259/